# Cordova building error on Windows

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

I am having a tremendous problem with cordova. For some reason, the command `cordova build` gives me the following error and I cannot figure out why. I try to do a simple andoid application on Windows 7.

```
   C:\Users\User\Documents\Cordova\workshop>cordova build
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\User\Documents\Cordova\workshop\platforms\
android\cordova\build.bat""
[Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\t
ools\android.BAT
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

C:\Users\User\Documents\Cordova\workshop>
```

Do you have any advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: Follow the steps it's telling you

Comment: The error is telling you - you are missing the *Android SDK #22*. It is also telling you how to install it. Follow the steps, starting with *Hint*.

Comment: Yes, indeed! It worked after installing the mentioned packages.